# How to set dynamically count Items in onsen ui lazy load

Tags: onsen-ui

Please help me with the dynamic setting of total item count in "onsen ui" jQuery.

**In example the count item is set as hard coded as below:**

```js
countItems: function() {
    return 10000;
}
```

In my case the data is coming from the JSON call that can be of any length so what will be the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Please try to format your questions correctly. Use the preview function to verify that it's the way you want it. Badly formatted questions tend to get no answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some source array that you want to use in your list you can just return the length of the list:

```
countItems: function() {
  return myList.length;
}
```

Comment: but how do i fill the mylist as it must global so that countitem can function receive. ? and can i call the delegate using any function

Comment: The delegate is called automatically by Onsen UI. You just need to define it.